# While I am running the below code I'm getting error :

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

code:

```
model = BertWSD.from_pretrained(model_dir)
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_dir)
# add new special token
if '[TGT]' not in tokenizer.additional_special_tokens:
    tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'additional_special_tokens': ['[TGT]']})
    assert '[TGT]' in tokenizer.additional_special_tokens
    model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))
    
model.to(DEVICE)
model.eval()
```

For some reason I keep getting a strange error whenever I run the code:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
    625             try:
--> 626                 state_dict = torch.load(resolved_archive_file, map_location="cpu")
    627             except Exception:

3 frames
RuntimeError: unexpected EOF, expected 5298350 more bytes. The file might be corrupted.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py in from_pretrained(cls, pretrained_model_name_or_path, *model_args, **kwargs)
    627             except Exception:
    628                 raise OSError(
--> 629                     "Unable to load weights from pytorch checkpoint file. "
    630                     "If you tried to load a PyTorch model from a TF 2.0 checkpoint, please set from_tf=True. "
    631                 )

OSError: Unable to load weights from pytorch checkpoint file. If you tried to load a PyTorch model from a TF 2.0 checkpoint, please set from_tf=True.
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be more specific about your issue in the title.

Comment: What is the content of `model_dir`? How did you get those files? What is the import for `BertWSD`?